# drop foreign key constraint on DB2 table through alter table

Tags: db2-400

I have a DB2 (for IBMi) table created as below. I would like to drop the forign key constraint while running in an SQLRPGLE program. Is this possible?

```
 create table grid_action_details(id integer not null                   
   generated always as identity                                         
 (start with 1 increment by 1)                                          
  PRIMARY KEY,grid_details_id integer,foreign key(grid_details_id)      
 references grid_details(id),action_code_details_id integer,            
 foreign key(action_code_details_id)                                    
 references action_code_details(id),action_code_status varchar(2),      
 created_date date default                                              
 current_date,created_by varchar(30),                                   
 last_updated_date date default current_date,updated_by                 
 varchar(30),required_parameter clob);
```

I tried the below syntax but it just doesn't seem to work for me:

```
ALTER TABLE table-name
      DROP FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name 


alter table iesqafile.grid_action_details                 
            drop foreign key action_code_details_id       
ACTION_CODE_DETAILS_ID in IESQAFILE type *N not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You drop the FK constraint via name, not via column.

Since you didn't specify one during create, you'll need to look to see what name the system generated.

Always a best practice to name things yourself.
`CONSTAINT <name> FOREIGN KEY (<columns>)`

```
create table grid_action_details (
      id integer not null generated always as identity (
      start with 1 increment by 1
    )
      ,constraint grid_action_details_pk 
          primary key
      ,grid_details_id integer
      ,constraint grid_details_fk 
          foreign key (grid_details_id) 
          references grid_details (id)
      ,action_code_details_id integer
      ,constraint action_code_details_fk 
          foreign key (action_code_details_id) 
          references action_code_details (id)
      ,action_code_status varchar(2)
      ,created_date date default current_date
      ,created_by varchar(30)
      ,last_updated_date date default current_date
      ,updated_by varchar(30)
      ,required_parameter clob
    );
```

Now you can drop by the known name

```
alter table iesqafile.grid_action_details                 
            drop foreign key action_code_details_fk
```

**EDIT**
To find the generated name use:

- the ACS Schema component
- DSPFD
- SQL against one of the [catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=reference-db2-i-catalog-views) (QSYS2.SYSCST, SYSIBM.SQLFOREIGNKEYS, SYSIBM.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS )

Comment: How do I find the known name? I tried to open up the table in DBU and use the Field name displayed but that also didnt work? Is there any way to find this information?

Comment: alter table GRID_ACTION_details                
                 DROP FOREIGN KEY GRID_00001   ||
GRID_00001 in IESQAFILE type *N not found. This is how i found the system name: SELECT SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =    
'GRID_ACTION_DETAILS' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'IESQAFILE' AND              
COLUMN_NAME = 'ACTION_CODE_DETAILS_ID'

Comment: @theju112t see edit

Comment: you've found the system generated name for the column, not the constraint.